# Parent attribute not passing to child | Flutter Stateful Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having this error when trying to pass an attribute to a child in a stateful widget:

[image]

If someone could help me I'll be very thankful!
Here's the code:

```
class SingleComponent extends StatefulWidget {

  final String name;
  final String image1;
  final String image2;
  final String image3;
  final String description;
  final String utilities;
  final String video1;
  final String video2;


  int current_section = 0;
  Color info_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);
  Color videos_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);
  Color preguntas_color = Color(0xffBDE3BE);

  SingleComponent(this.name, this.image1, this.image2, this.image3,
      this.description, this.utilities, this.video1, this.video2);

  @override
  _SingleComponentState createState() => _SingleComponentState();
}

class _SingleComponentState extends State<SingleComponent> {

  
  List widget_printed = [
    ComponentDescription(widget.description, "Hola", widget.name),
  ];
```

Comment: You can do lazy initialization, `late List widget_printed = [...]`.

Comment: Already tried and didn't work :C Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

initialize using the **late** keyword

```
late var temp = ComponentDescription(widget.description, "Hola", widget.name);
List widget_printed = [
    temp,
  ];
```

Comment: Hi, I can't use "late" as my flutter app is not using null safety :(
Is there any other possibility to handle this? please